# MS Access query taking long time to execute

Tags: ms-access

I am using the following simple query, which taking more than a minute to execute.
Will someone help me out

```
SELECT qryCredit_Points.Employee_ID, qryCredit_Points.First_Name,
qryCredit_Points.Last_Name, Sum(qryCredit_Points.TotalCredit) AS   
SumOfTotalCredit

FROM (  
SELECT emp.*, 
          (SELECT top 1 a.attend_date 
           FROM Attendance AS a 
           WHERE a.ID_Employee=at.ID_Employee and a.attend_date > at.attend_date 
           order by a.attend_date asc ) 
           AS NextDate, 
           IIf(IsNull(NextDate),Now(),Nextdate) AS next123, 
           Next123-at.attend_date AS difference, at.attend_date, 
           IIf(at.attend_date+90<Next123,1,0) AS Day90Credit, 
           IIf(at.attend_date+90<Next123,at.attend_date+90,at.attend_date+365) AS CreditDate, 
           IIf((Day90Credit=0 And CreditDate<Now()) Or Day90Credit=1,1,0) AS TotalCredit 
           FROM attendance AS [at], 
           Employees AS emp WHERE (((emp.Employee_ID)=[at].[ID_Employee])) 
) AS qryCredit_Points

GROUP BY qryCredit_Points.Employee_ID, qryCredit_Points.First_Name, 
qryCredit_Points.Last_Name;;
```

Comment: How much data do you have? What have you tried? Have you tried analyzing the query to see why it takes a long time? What does Google say?

Comment: I tried analyzing got no suggestion and table have only 2900 rows, tried google and use index but same issue slow, all others query works find

Comment: Assuming `qryCredit_Points` is another query, we may need to see its SQL.    However you probably want those `Employee_ID`, `First_Name`, and `Last_Name` fields indexed (in the base table which contains them).

Comment: It got little bit faster after creating index on First_name and Last_Name, the employee_ID is a Primary Key. Here is the SQL for query

Comment: SELECT emp.*, (SELECT  top 1  a.attend_date FROM Attendance a  WHERE a.ID_Employee=at.ID_Employee and a.attend_date > at.attend_date order by a.attend_date asc ) AS NextDate, IIf(IsNull(NextDate),Now(),Nextdate) AS next123, Next123-at.attend_date AS difference, at.attend_date, IIf(at.attend_date+90<Next123,1,0) AS Day90Credit, IIf(at.attend_date+90<Next123,at.attend_date+90,at.attend_date+365) AS CreditDate, IIf((Day90Credit=0 And CreditDate<Now()) Or Day90Credit=1,1,0) AS TotalCredit
FROM attendance AS [at], Employees AS emp
WHERE (((emp.Employee_ID)=[at].[ID_Employee]));

Comment: How quickly does `qryCredit_Points` run?

Comment: You should add an index on `attend_date` if it's not already indexed.

Comment: QryCredit_points run blink of an eye

Comment: It got way faster now after adding the index on First_name, Last_name and on Attend_date.

Comment: Thanks Hawken Riven, HansUp and Mark C for your help

Comment: Can I get little vote

Comment: Up please also will you explain the Scratch table in your comments?